# How to make above and below distance of pivot equal in genealogytree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, genealogytree

How to make above and below  distance of pivot equal in `genealogytree`? By default it is symmetric. e.g.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost]{%,box={width=2cm,height=1cm}

parent
{
    g[id=b]{b}

    parent
    {
        g[id=c]{c}


    }
    parent
    {
        g[id=d]{d}
    }
}

}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After changing box dimensions using `box={width=2cm,height=1cm}` tts symmetry disturbed.

[image]

Comment: did you have a look at the previous answer with parent configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**all options =off**

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,
%               box={width=2cm,height=1cm},
%               node size =2cm,
%               level size=1cm,
%               level distance=3cm
                ]
                {
                    parent{   g[id=b]{b}
                            parent  { g[id=c]{c}   }
                                 parent    {   g[id=d]{d}    }}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**with option box width and height=on**
unbalanced

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,
                box={width=2cm,height=1cm},
%               node size =2cm,
%               level size=1cm,
%               level distance=3cm
                ]
                {
                    parent{   g[id=b]{b}
                            parent  { g[id=c]{c}   }
                                 parent    {   g[id=d]{d}    }}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**with box option=off but node size=2cm and level size =1cm**
balanced

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,
%               box={width=2cm,height=1cm},
                node size =2cm,
                level size=1cm,
%               level distance=3cm
                ]
                {
                    parent{   g[id=b]{b}
                            parent  { g[id=c]{c}   }
                                 parent    {   g[id=d]{d}    }}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**adding another optionfor level distance =3cm**
  balanced

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,
%               box={width=2cm,height=1cm},
                node size =2cm,
                level size=1cm,
                level distance=3cm
                ]
                {
                    parent{   g[id=b]{b}
                            parent  { g[id=c]{c}   }
                                 parent    {   g[id=d]{d}    }}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```